# Change DataFrame orientation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I am trying to change the way my dataFrame appears, from 7x2 I want it to become 2x7. Let me show an example below:

```
                 0                       1
0              time                  3362.0
1              type  vehicle enters traffic
2            person          80520_1_Person
3              link                   97101
4           vehicle          80520_1_Person
5       networkMode                     car
6  relativePosition                     1.0
```

I actually want to end up the: time, type, person, link, vehicle, networkMode, relativePosition to become my column names and all the entries to go to the corresponding column position respectively.

```
             time       type           person        link        vehicle    netMode   relatPos
0            3362.0  vehicle enters  80520_1_Person  97101    80520_1_Person   car       1.0
1            3362.0  vehicle enters  80520_1_Person  97101    80520_1_Person   car       1.0
2            3362.0  vehicle enters  80520_1_Person  97101    80520_1_Person   car       1.0
3            3362.0  vehicle enters  80520_1_Person  97101    80520_1_Person   car       1.0
...
N            3362.0  vehicle enters  80520_1_Person  97101    80520_1_Person   car       1.0
```

I am trying with pivot() but apparently I am missing something here, cause I cannot make it work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `df.set_index(0).T` ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) in addition to `df.set_index(0).T`

```
N = 5
pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.set_index(0).T.values, N, axis = 0), columns = df[0])
```

prints:

```
      time                   type   person          link    vehicle   networkMode   relativePosition
0   3362.0  vehicle enters traffic  80520_1_Person  97101   80520_1_Person  car 1.0
1   3362.0  vehicle enters traffic  80520_1_Person  97101   80520_1_Person  car 1.0
2   3362.0  vehicle enters traffic  80520_1_Person  97101   80520_1_Person  car 1.0
3   3362.0  vehicle enters traffic  80520_1_Person  97101   80520_1_Person  car 1.0
4   3362.0  vehicle enters traffic  80520_1_Person  97101   80520_1_Person  car 1.0
```